# List all XML files in directory, from newest to oldest

Tags: find, ls

A mix between:

```
ls -rtl | more
```

and

```
find . -type f -name '*.xml' | more
```

Just filtering XML files.

Comment: perhaps `find . -type f -name '*.xml' -exec ls -rtl {} \; | more`

Comment: Don't you mean `the oldest entries first ` when you ask `in reverse time order`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this command:

```
ls -tl *.xml
```

This will produce a long output list of all XML files, ordered from newest to oldest.
If you want them ordered from oldest to newest, add a `-r` flag.

Comment: The -rt modifiers are not ordering in reverse time order.

Comment: In my system it does -- from oldest to newest.

Comment: ok So I was confused. I don't need the -r option because I wanted to sort from newest to oldest

Comment: @user3514092 Please update your question with more details then!

Comment: @saisasanka done already

Comment: This is the simplest solution which works. Only thing I needed to add "| more" because the list is way too long.

Comment: If you want to list files in current directory then but if your to search before listing then...

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
find . -type f -name "*.xml" -exec ls -lrt {} +
```

You may want to add the `-maxdepth` option (if available with your `find` version) to reduce the listing.

**EDIT:**  For the REVISED question, try

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.xml" -exec ls -lt {} +
```

Comment: The -rt modifiers are not ordering in reverse time order. Plus, I don't need recursivity in subdirectories.

Comment: Then, drop the `r` option to `ls`.Does your find offer the `-maxdepth` option?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
dir -lt *.xml
```

If you just need file list , get the last column

```
dir -lt *.xml | awk '{print $NF}'
```